# Environment toggle in Sumologic dashboard

Tags: sumologic

I've created a dashboard to monitor errors & warnings for my app.

I'm logging to separate locations (_sourceHost) based on environment (uat, prod).

I'd like to have a toggle on the dashboard so I can easily switch between UAT & Prod, rather than having to maintain two dashboards.

I'd tried adding a filter but the best I could achieve was a textbox where I enter the _sourceost...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this with a [search template](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/How-to-Build-a-Search/Search-Templates). Basically, set up a parameter that's the value of the _sourceHost:

```
_sourceHost={{source_host}}
| the rest of your query here...
```

Then in the "manage parameter settings" dialog, you could "Set Values for Parameter" to your environment key/value mapping.

Then when you [add it to the dashboard](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/How-to-Build-a-Search/Search-Templates#Create_Dashboards_from_Search_Templates) it should treat that parameter as a filter, and I *believe* the values you set up will dropdown from the filter to be selected.